# Atributo em html que ao clicar no texto a opção no checkbox é selecionada

Tags: html

Boa tarde, Gostaria de saber se existe algum atributo em HTML que ao usuário clicar no texto da opção em checkbox, o campo é selecionado, não precisando clicar bem certinho dentro daquele quadrado minisculo.
Sei que dá para fazer com o label, mas fora o label existe outra opção? apenas em HTML sem javascript?

Comment: Boa tarde! Por que não pode ser com label?

Comment: Não existe atributo para isso porque usar o label é a solução definida na especificação do HTML.

Comment: Vc sabe que vc pode ter mais de um label para o mesmo botão né? Se o label foi feito para isso eh Pq ele deve ser usado e não existe outro opção além do label para isso

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/sampaNight/1ftsv3w0/3/

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="campo" id="campo">
Selecione
</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="campo1" id="campo1">
<label for="campo1">
Selecione
</label>
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Não sei porque foi colocado como ponto negativo. Impressionante tentamos ajudar. Investimos tempo nisso e vem alguém e negativa sua resposta.

Comment: Amigo não foi eu que te negative, mas aparentemente te deram -1 porque vc não respondeu ao que o autor perguntou, na verdade me parece que vc nem leu a pergunta ate o final antes de responder... Veja que na pergunta esta assim *" Sei que dá para fazer com o label, mas fora o label existe outra opção? apenas em HTML sem javascript?"* acho que isso deixa bem claro o seu -1

Comment: Eu li sim só achei que seria bom colocar as formas que conheço com o label. Realmente não deveria ter respondido.

Comment: Se ele deixou bem clara que não quer com label qual o sentido de responder falando da label? Ele tbm fala que não quer com jS, qq um que responder com JS provavelmente tbm vai levar um -1, sua resposta não faz sentido para essa pergunta, talvez vc.possa usar em outro momento

Comment: Que legal receber um positivo aqui. O stackoverflow aqui do Brasil tem tanta gente com milhares de pontos tentando deixar tudo tão perfeito para eles que acabam inibindo a comunidade. Os administradores sempre negativando os outros, não deixando ninguém arriscar nada que fica até chato fazer alguma coisa. Obrigado e parabéns.